# Hibernate ImprovedNamingStrategy not working correctly

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, naming-conventions, hbm2ddl

using this in my hibernate cfg:

```
<property name="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
```

This should make all my tables and column `snake_case` in database.

But it is just making them `camelCase`.

**What could be the problem?**

```
private String myName;
```

in my database it is still `myName(varchar(255))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy` programmatically worked.

```
configuration.setNamingStrategy(ImprovedNamingStrategy.INSTANCE);
```

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-programmatic

Still wondering why it didn't work from XML, should work.

Answer (score 4):

@Jaanus was too hasty in rejecting the links provided by @Renjith

The link states that it does work in XML but has to be injected as a property of the session factory as shown in the XML code extract below:

---

```
    <!-- object to relational mapping configuration -->
  <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <property name="map">
          <map>
            <entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect" />

            <entry key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="validate" />

            <entry key="hibernate.connection.charSet" value="UTF-8" />

            <entry key="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <entry key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="0" />
          </map>
        </property>
    </property>
    <property name="namingStrategy">
      <bean class="org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy" />
    </property>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    ...
  </bean>
```